# Can't login using serial on ttyO0 - BeagleBone Black

Tags: embedded, tty

I boot Beaglebone Black, connected to my desktop by serial.

It was working great, until now.
Beagle is booting, output shows up on the console, but at the end I can't log in.
I can't type the login, nor anything (nothing, that I type shows on the screen).

I am using Angstrom distribution.
This is the end of output from the Putty:

```
Starting Console Manager...
[  OK  ] Found device /dev/ttyO0.
     Starting Serial Getty on ttyO0...
[  OK  ] Started Console Manager.
[   15.076001] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   15.163885] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted

.---O---.
|       |                  .-.           o o
|   |   |-----.-----.-----.| |   .----..-----.-----.
|       |     | __  |  ---'| '--.|  .-'|     |     |
|   |   |  |  |     |---  ||  --'|  |  |  '  | | | |
'---'---'--'--'--.  |-----''----''--'  '-----'-'-'-'
                -'  |
                '---'

The Angstrom Distribution beaglebone ttyO0

Angstrom v2012.12 - Kernel 3.8.13

beaglebone login: [  OK  ] Reached target Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Found device /dev/ttyGS0.
         Starting Serial Getty on ttyGS0...
[  OK  ] Started Serial Getty on ttyGS0.
[  OK  ] Reached target Login Prompts.
[  OK  ] Reached target Multi-User.
[  OK  ] Reached target Graphical Interface.
[   18.974513] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   19.034955] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   19.089415] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   19.296647] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   31.664635] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: commit=0
[   43.655795] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   43.698762] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   43.759312] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   43.796401] tilcdc 4830e000.fb: mode 832x624@75 is blacklisted
[   44.038548] fuse init (API version 7.20)
```